# how i can create list from firestore data

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to create list from firestore data
to add suggestions/autocomplete in text field,  any help please?

**example list:**

```
  static final List<String> commodity = [
    'Banana',
    'Mango',
    'Orange',
  ];
```

**wanted list from firestore:**

```
 static getSuggestion(String suggestion) async =>
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("QFS")
          .where('commodity', isEqualTo: suggestion)
          .get()
          .then((snap) {
        return snap.docs;
      });
}
```

**my whole code:**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_typeahead/flutter_typeahead.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _selectedCommodity1;
  var _selectedCommodity2;
  TextEditingController commodityFiled1 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController commodityFiled2 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text("QFS"),
            ),
            body: Form(
                child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 5, bottom: 10, right: 20, left: 20),
                    child: Column(children: [
                      TypeAheadFormField(
                        textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                            controller: commodityFiled1,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Commodity1',
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.receipt_rounded,
                                  color: Colors.black87,
                                ))),
                        suggestionsCallback: (pattern) {
                          return CommodityService.getSuggestions(pattern);
                        },
                        itemBuilder: (context, String suggestion) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(suggestion),
                          );
                        },
                        transitionBuilder:
                            (context, suggestionsBox, controller) {
                          return suggestionsBox;
                        },
                        onSuggestionSelected: (String suggestion) {
                          commodityFiled1.text = suggestion;
                        },
                        onSaved: (value) => _selectedCommodity1 = value!,
                      ),
                      TypeAheadFormField(
                        textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                            controller: commodityFiled2,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Commodity2',
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.receipt_rounded,
                                  color: Colors.black87,
                                ))),
                        suggestionsCallback: (pattern) {
                          return getSuggestion(pattern);
                        },
                        itemBuilder: (context, dynamic suggestion) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(suggestion),
                          );
                        },
                        transitionBuilder:
                            (context, suggestionsBox, controller) {
                          return suggestionsBox;
                        },
                        onSuggestionSelected: (dynamic suggestion) {
                          commodityFiled2.text = suggestion;
                        },
                        onSaved: (value) => _selectedCommodity2 = value!,
                      ),
                    ])))));
  }

  static getSuggestion(String suggestion) async =>
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("QFS")
          .where('commodity', isEqualTo: suggestion)
          .get()
          .then((snap) {
        return snap.docs;
      });
}

class CommodityService {
  static final List<String> commodity = [
    'Banana',
    'Mango',
    'Orange',
  ];

  static List<String> getSuggestions(String query) {
    List<String> matches = [];
    matches.addAll(commodity);
    matches.retainWhere((s) => s.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()));
    return matches;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Clarification**: *From my understanding, you have documents in your collection that each of them has the property `commodity` (type `String`) and you want to fetch only the document that has a specific commodity.*

Open your Google Firestore Database dashboard and check which types you can have the documents of your collection.
[image]
Click `Add document` to check the types.
[image]

Check the [Firestore docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes).

Inside `snapshot.data`, there's `docs` (every document of your collection).

The code is from docs:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['full_name']),
              subtitle: Text(data['company']),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

The code above shows how to convert every document (type [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html)) to a JSON format (that can be represented with `Map<String, dynamic>`). To access to your field `commodity` (type `String`), put this `data['commodity']`. For doc `id`, you'll need access with `document.id`, because it isn't inside the `document.data()` method.

Then on `suggestionCallback` (I read TypeAheadField of [`flutter_typeahead` API](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_typeahead/latest/flutter_typeahead/TypeAheadField-class.html), you have to return to it a [List (it's an Iterable)](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.3/dart-core/List-class.html) of some type (like `List<String>`).

I never tried [this Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead#material-example-2) before, but I would edit `getSuggestion()`:

```dart
static Future<List<String>> getSuggestion(String suggestion) async =>
      return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("QFS")
          .where('commodity', isEqualTo: suggestion)
          .get()
          .then((snap) {
            final docs = snap.data!.docs;

            return docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return data['<fieldname of your document, e.g., "country" or "commodity"'];

          }).toList(),
      });
```

Write your solution on comments section.

Comment: i already have my collection and fields just i want to convert it to a list, like the example above

Comment: i want to use it in suggestions/autocomplete text field

Comment: I've just updated the answer.

Comment: could you please see the whole code i update it, thanks for your try, hope you get some idea what i want to accomplish and  help me to fix it .

Comment: Check the answer

Comment: thanks for the hint but it show me this now "The return type 'List<dynamic>' isn't a 'FutureOr<List<String>>', as required by the closure's context"

Comment: unfortunately it not work in my case.